# Windows 10 search bar searches only once

Tags: windows, windows-10, search-indexing

Good time of the day,
I'm facing really strange issue:

1. When system is booted, i can search for items
2. As soon as i close the search bar, and reopen it i cannot search anymore
3. When i restart the search service, I'm able to search again until the search bar is closed again

Been trying to find a solution, but none of them worked.

What i have tried:

1. Rebuilding the index
2. Moving it to a different drive
3. Many other "solutions"

I am using the latest build of Fall Creators Update and Windows 10 'Home' (not Pro)

Any help is really appreciated!